# How to get total in django template

Tags: python, django

My database have one col namely **MaxSubjectMarks**

MaxSubjectMarks (Column name)
10
20
30
40
50

150  (I want 150 output)

q = SubjectsMaximumMarks.objects.filter(SessionCode=SessionResult,ClassCode=StudentClass).values('MaxSubjectMarks').annotate(total=Sum("MaxSubjectMarks"))

{{ q }}

output =>
<QuerySet [{'MaxSubjectMarks': '10', 'total': 10.0}, {'MaxSubjectMarks': '20', 'total': 20.0}, {'MaxSubjectMarks': '30', 'total': 30.0}, {'MaxSubjectMarks': '40', 'total': 40.0}, {'MaxSubjectMarks': '50', 'total': 50.0}]>

i want output

Total = 150

Comment: you need aggregate not annotate

Comment: {'total': 150.0} Thanks Vishal it is working now